# How to get the project path at Design Time

Tags: c#, path, components, design-time

I use a component (System.ComponentModel.Component) and I want to get the application path of my project in order to create a file within it.

Thx

Florian

Comment: are you working in windows forms or wpf?

Answer (score 5):

The only thing that seemed to work (consistently) for me was obtaining EnvDTE.DTE (from the IServiceProvider you get from EditValue()), i.e.:

```
EnvDTE.DTE dte = envProvider.GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE)) as EnvDTE.DTE;
string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(dte.Solution.FullName);
```

When I tried using Assembly.GetXAssembly, I got the temporary path VS uses in design-time.

Comment: i believe you are right. But just can get this to work in VB.

Answer (score 3):

Just call GetMyPath which is defined as

```
string GetMyPath([CallerFilePath] string from = null)
{
   return from;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.

Comment: It does not work. When I dragged my compoment which have this method :

public override void InitializeNewComponent(IDictionary defaultValues)
{
  MessageBox.Show(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
}

The messagebox appears with that : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\

Comment: I suggest you test application with VS?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
 New Uri(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().CodeBase).AbsolutePath
```

("CallingAssembly" because you can put the method to retrieve the execution path into the service layer (assembly))

Comment: it doesn't work : here the result 
C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: [Project (bin) folder path at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723172/project-bin-folder-path-at-compile-time)

With this technique you could "Build" (once) and after that use the generated file to get the project location at DesignTime. This would work workspace independent.

Answer (score 0):

I think Robert is almost right.

This seems to work:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

Comment: This returns the temporary VS path at design time

Answer (score 0):

```
string solutionpath = Directory.GetParent(Application.ExecutablePath).Parent.Parent.Parent.FullName;
```

I think this is the best solution, because you dont have to add any library more than "Using System.IO" :)

Answer (score 0):

I did a simple test ( just as a temporary design, I added a string property to hold the current directory value ) ( *I do not describe the all process of data binding*. See some of my post about design time / run-time binding )

In the empty constructor of the main window ViewModel class ( dedicated to design time binding )

```
public MainWindow_ViewModel():this(null)
{
    dtpath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    Console.WriteLine("CTor finished");
}
```

In the mainwindow.xaml file I added a textbox to display the result ( don't mind the grid row value )

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding dtpath}" Grid.Row="3"/>
```

And I got in the design view of VS ( like Florian's comment stated , but with a newer value 4 years after):
**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about WPF designer, please use "Context" property/type

**Details:-**
In Design time you have instance of modelItem (I assume it, you know it) if not then you can instantiate it in Override implementation of Activate method

// in  DesignAdorner class

```
public class DesignAdorner : PrimarySelectionAdornerProvider
{
      protected override void Activate(ModelItem item)
        {
                modelItem = item;
        }
}
```

Now you can access the current application path using following single line code

```
string aplicationPathDir = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(modelItem.Context.ToString()).FullName;
```

Let me know, if it does not help you.

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to envdte80 which is in .NetFrameWork 4.5 Assemblies.

```
DTE2 dte = DesignTimeProjectPath.Processes.GetDTE();
    if (dte != null)
     {
        var solution = dte.Solution;
        if (solution != null)
         {
             string baseDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(solution.FullName);
             MessageBox.Show(baseDir);
         }
     }

  namespace DesignTimeProjectPath
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This class takes care of fetching the correct DTE instance for the current process
        /// The current implementation works it way down from Visual Studio version 20 to 10 so
        /// it should be farely version independent
        /// </summary>
        public static class Processes
        {
            [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
            private static extern void CreateBindCtx(int reserved, out IBindCtx ppbc);
            [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
            private static extern void GetRunningObjectTable(int reserved, out IRunningObjectTable prot);

            private const int m_MaxVersion = 20;
            private const int m_MinVersion = 10;

            internal static DTE2 GetDTE()
            {
                DTE2 dte = null;

                for (int version = m_MaxVersion; version >= m_MinVersion; version--)
                {
                    string versionString = string.Format("VisualStudio.DTE.{0}.0", version);

                    dte = Processes.GetCurrent(versionString);

                    if (dte != null)
                    {
                        return dte;
                    }
                }

                throw new Exception(string.Format("Can not get DTE object tried versions {0} through {1}", m_MaxVersion, m_MinVersion));
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// When multiple instances of Visual Studio are running there also multiple DTE available
            /// The method below takes care of selecting the right DTE for the current process
            /// </summary>
            /// <remarks>
            /// Found this at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724381/get-the-reference-of-the-dte2-object-in-visual-c-sharp-2010/27057854#27057854
            /// </remarks>
            private static DTE2 GetCurrent(string versionString)
            {
                Process parentProc = GetParent(Process.GetCurrentProcess());
                int parentProcId = parentProc.Id;
                string rotEntry = String.Format("!{0}:{1}", versionString, parentProcId);

                IRunningObjectTable rot;
                GetRunningObjectTable(0, out rot);

                IEnumMoniker enumMoniker;
                rot.EnumRunning(out enumMoniker);
                enumMoniker.Reset();

                IntPtr fetched = IntPtr.Zero;
                IMoniker[] moniker = new IMoniker[1];

                while (enumMoniker.Next(1, moniker, fetched) == 0)
                {
                    IBindCtx bindCtx;
                    CreateBindCtx(0, out bindCtx);
                    string displayName;
                    moniker[0].GetDisplayName(bindCtx, null, out displayName);

                    if (displayName == rotEntry)
                    {
                        object comObject;

                        rot.GetObject(moniker[0], out comObject);

                       return (EnvDTE80.DTE2)comObject;
                    }
                }

                return null;
            }

            private static Process GetParent(Process process)
            {
                var processName = process.ProcessName;
                var nbrOfProcessWithThisName = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName).Length;
                for (var index = 0; index < nbrOfProcessWithThisName; index++)
                {
                    var processIndexdName = index == 0 ? processName : processName + "#" + index;
                    var processId = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "ID Process", processIndexdName);
                    if ((int)processId.NextValue() == process.Id)
                    {
                        var parentId = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Creating Process ID", processIndexdName);
                        return Process.GetProcessById((int)parentId.NextValue());
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```