# Get relative path to file at design time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, relative-path

I am building a Windows phone 8 app.

At design time I load a sample XML file to get sample data.
It works well but I want to use path to file that is relative to solution root so it can work for all developpers with the same code.

Here is my current code:

```
var path = @"C:\Users\Tom\MyProject\SampleData\stub.xml";
xml = new StreamReader(path).ReadToEnd();
```

I tried a relative path like @"SampleData\stub.xml". It works on phone but at design time I get this error:

> DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\SampleData\login.xml'.

Comment: The relative path has to have some base to relate to. I guess it is your working direcotry. ;-)
Include the file in your project and set action: copy if newer

Comment: This isn't exactly the same question, but basically you need to use one of the solutions from this question I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425944/how-to-get-the-project-path-at-design-time

Comment: Thanks Dana, here is the only solution tha worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723172/project-bin-folder-path-at-compile-time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I did :

```
var path = "SampleData/stub.xml";
var res = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative));
xml = new StreamReader(res.Stream).ReadToEnd();
```